# Size of Binary log file in Mysql Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, linux, mysql-5.1, mysqlbinlog

I have a master - server replication setup in Linux servers.

Master Configuration details :

```
 MySQL version is 5.1 and replication mode is MIXED type.
```

Slave Configuration details :

```
 MySQL version is 5.6
```

If i insert single record , then it is getting replicated to slave.

When i am running a script to insert thousand of records at master , it is not getting replicated.

When i see the size of binary log file , it is of 908 MB
and when i see the size of relay log file , it is 560 KB.

Does , size of a binary log file matters ?
or 
what is the probable cause of this.

Below is master cnf details :

```
  [mysqld]

  datadir=/var/lib/mysql
  socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
  user=mysql
  # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
    symbolic-links=0
    bind-address = #master IP# ( not showing here )
    port=3306
    wait_timeout=90
    net_read_timeout=90
    connect_timeout=90
    max_connections=100
    lower_case_table_names=1
    log-bin=mysql-bin
    binlog_format=MIXED
    server-id=1

[mysqld_safe]
     log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
     pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: post `show slave status` output of slave.

Comment: Do any records at all get replicated when you run the script? Can you please give more detail about how you are running the script?

Comment: when running the script at master end , not even a single record is replicating , yes but when i just insert one record manually , it get replicate.
Script are designed to take data from Oracle and insert it into MySQL database.
In this script every table of oracle is mapped with MySQL table and insertion takes place in the Master database.

Comment: An insert is an insert whether it happens from a script or the console manually. Please show in your question how you are running the script or what is in it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue myself only using following process :

1. Change the replication mode to ROW.
2. Restrict the size of max_binlog_size=30M

In this way binary log file cant be of huge size and easy to replicate.

Comment: The size of the binlog has no impact on ease of replication.  Reads are done from where it left off.

Comment: Switching to ROW may be advisable, but won't solve the OP's problem, except by coincidence.